# Unable to get cookie value in Yii2

Tags: php, cookies, yii2

I have set cookie on a page using code :

```
$newCookie= new \yii\web\Cookie();
$newCookie->name='cookie_name';
$newCookie->value='test value';
$newCookie->expire = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 180;
$cookie=Yii::$app->getResponse()->getCookies()->add($newCookie);
```

But when on another page i tried to check that cookie is set or not i am not able to get cookie 
 value :

```
if(Yii::$app->getResponse()->getCookies()->has('cookie_name')){
    if(Yii::$app->getResponse()->getCookies()->getValue('cookie_name')){
        echo "cookie available";die;
    }
}
```

Can anyone let me know what wrong i am doing???

Many Thanks

M.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use request component to read cookies :

```
if(Yii::$app->getRequest()->getCookies()->has('cookie_name')){
}
```

Read more : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html

> Both yii\web\Request and yii\web\Response maintain a collection of cookies via the property named cookies. The cookie collection in the former represents the cookies submitted in a request, while the cookie collection in the latter represents the cookies that are to be sent to the user.

Comment: Did you update your code to use request (for reading) instead of response ?

Comment: Soju.. you were right. For reading we need to use request and to write we need to use response.right?